# How to call super classes constructor from a subclass?

Tags: lua

I've searched around for quite a while, I didn't find a possible way.

Obe possible solution I have in mind is to make the super class call a method called subInit(), and put all of the subclasses init code ibside subInit. But this seems like a very hacky way. I don't like it

Comment: have you gone through: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationTutorial ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a constructor of a parent class like this:

```
function SuperClass:construct()
    -- init of self
end
```

In the subclass constructor you could do simply this:

```
function SubClass:construct() 
    SuperClass.construct(self)
    -- more init of self
end
```